# Error when i try to run a sharepoint 2016 solution from my VS 2015 Community Edition:- "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

Tags: development, solution-package, installation, 2016, visual-studio-2015

I have the following :-

1. Windows server r2 2012.
2. SharePoint server 2016.
3. i download Visual studio 2015 community.
4. i download  [Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683) .
5. i created a new empty sharepoint 2016 project inside VS 2015 community.
6. inside the project i added a new Event Receiver.
7. i build the project successfully.

but when i click on start debugging the got this weird exeception :-

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.   SharePointProject6

here is how my SP 2016 solution looks like:-

[image]

also my project is showing this warning:-

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Unhandled exception occurred while calling method
>   'projectService_ProjectInitialized' of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport.PackageBootstrapper,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Message: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.    SharePointProject6      0

**EDIT**
now i install and configure workflow manager 1.0 inside my sharepoint 2016. Then after that i tried to create a new sharepoint farm solution using visual studio 2015 , but i got the exact same error...

> Unhandled exception occurred while calling method
>   'projectService_ProjectInitialized' of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport.PackageBootstrapper,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Message: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   SharePointProject6 0

now i checked my current references from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`

and here what i got:-

[image]

so seems even after installing the workflow manager inside my sharepoint 2016 server , i am still receiving the same error.
just a note i verified that my workflow manager is configured well, as all these validation steps are working fine,, this means that the workflow manager is configured well inside my SP 2016 server:-

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34457.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-validation-of-configuration-of-workflow-manager-1-0.aspx

Comment: are you tried to create an empty SharePoint 2016 solution with a simple visual web part and check if it's working or not? also, I suggest to install 4.6.1  from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981 that is considered in-place update to the Microsoft .NET Framework 4, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.

Comment: @M.Qassas i tried the following:-  create a new Project >> chose SharePoint empty project >> Farm solution >> i add a new visual web part >> but when i start debugging i got the exact errors...

Comment: I would add 3a) Install Office developer tools RTM. It never works for me if I only install ODT Preview 2 without prior RTM installation.

Comment: @SlavenSemper can you advice more on your latest reply please?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error messages that you have posted, i am hazarding a guess that `Workflow manager` is not installed on your environment. I had a similar unrelated error that crashed my SP designer whenever i tried to open a site.

The issue turned out that i needed `Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.Proxy.dll` in my environment which is available when you install this workflow manager. So, i copy pasted the dll from a colleague's machine and it started working.

I would suggest that you install and configure the `Workflow Manager` on your environment and then try and debug the error. Its a long drawn process but once completed, the errors would be resolved automatically and you would be able to debug your code.

Waqas Sarwar, SP.SE's top contributor has written an excellent blog and provided step by step instructions to install and configure the workflow manager.

Reference - [Step by step installation of Workflow manager in SP 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx)

[SharePoint 2016 Workflow Manager installation step by step guide](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2016-Workflow-acd5ba2a)

[Workflow manager download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35375)

Comment: can you please check my edit to the original question.. thanks

Comment: now in my case i have installed WF manager 1.0 and it is configured well,, but i am unable to run my farm solution inside VS 2015 ..

Comment: hmm, can you download and install the latest office developer tools from this link and check - https://aka.ms/GetLatestOfficeDevTools ?

Comment: now i used the MS web platform installer 5.0 ,, and from there i installed "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 " the current version is 14.0. 23930.0 i did this 2 weeks ago.. so not sure if i need to install the one mentioned in ur link ...   as i should have the latest one already installed..